# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(x, name, value) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

When running this code

```
projectile <- data.table()
projectile$angle<- c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75)  
projectile$distance <- c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8)
ggplot() + geom_point( aes(projectile$angle, projectile$distance)  ) # Works
ggplot(projectile) + geom_point( aes(angle,distance) ) # Does not work
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(x, name, value) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Can anyone explain what this error means, why I have it and how to fix it, please?

UPDATE:
the same error occurs at earlier step if I use `data.frame`:

```
projectile <- data.frame()
projectile$angle<- c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75)
```

Error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, angle, value = c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75 : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 0
```

The reason why I dont create `data.frame(angle=c(..), distance=c(..)` right away is obviously that these values are NOT known until the user enters them later.

Comment: Why can't you created the dataset as `data.table(angle = c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75) , distance =  c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8))`

Comment: I showed the reason in my post.  Please check

Comment: You don't want to create empty `data.table` at the beginning. If the values are not known can you not do `angle <- c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75);distance <- c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8);` and then `projectile <- data.table(angle, distance)`?

Comment: No I can't - In our project, nothing is known about the table. Then a student is asked to add a column of measurements, which she does not yet what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be related to the way the dataset was created.  If we reconvert it to `data.table`, it would work

```
ggplot(setDT(setDF(projectile))) + 
       geom_point( aes(angle,distance) )
```

---

The `data.table` was created as a `NULL` object and then assigned columns.  Instead, it can be done

```
projectile <- data.table(angle = c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75) , distance =  c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8))
```

---

As we are assigning on a NULL object, the attributes for `row.names` are of length 0

```
row.names = integer(0)
```

When we construct the dataset in a proper way, it would show

```
row.names = c(NA, -5L)
```

in the `dput` output

---

If we want to start with a NULL object, use a `list`, then at the end, convert it to `data.frame` or `data.table`.  In that way, it will add the attributes for data.frame/data.table.  Note that `data.frame` is a `list` with elements (i.e. columns) of equal length

```
projectile <- list()
projectile$angle<- c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75) 
projectile$distance <- c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8)
projectile <- data.frame(projectile)
```

Comment: This is a great hack to resolve the problem: `projectile <- setDT(setDF(projectile))`. Now it works!      - However,  it works for `data.table` only , which is perfect with me, since stopped using `data.frame` in favour of `data.table` awhile ago. Is there the same easy way for `data.frame`?

Comment: @IVIM  YOu need to assign the `row.names(projectile) <- NULL`

Comment: @IVIM If you want to create from scratch, start with a `list`, and then convert it to `data.frame i.e. `projectile <- list(); projectile$angle<- c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75) ;
projectile$distance <- c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8); projectile <- data.frame(projectile)` and it should work

Comment: I will recommend `data.table` developers to add this is as new feature: being able to add columns to NULL data.table, without the need to use of any hacks.  - I was trying to introduce R to my 12-grade daughter   for her physics projects. And this issue became a bummer that freaked her out :(

Comment: @IVIM The initial assignment of NULL was not updating the row names.  I would reassign the row.names

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#Empty data table
projectile <- data.table()
#Add variables
projectile <- projectile[,list(angle=c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75),
                            distance=c(5.1, 8, 10,  8.5, 4.8)),]
#Plot                                 
ggplot(plotdat) + geom_point( aes(angle,distance) )
```

Output:

[image]